# Gauge-mediated SUSY breaking mechanism explained in simple terms

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, supersymmetry, higgs, symmetry-breaking

How can the basics of gauge-mediated SUSY breaking mechanism be explained in simple terms?

(sample explanation of EW SSB, for reference: “electroweak symmetry is broken due to a non-vanishing value of the Higgs field which couples to different components of EW lagrangian in different ways”.)

The explanation doesn’t have to be complete, rigorous or 100% correct, but some attempt would be greatly appreciated :)